# Como fazer um regex para tratar o texto desta forma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Considerando que eu tenho classes aleatórias, podendo ou não ter uma classe no parágrafo. Eu preciso colocar um parágrafo vazio, quando não houver um parágrafo vazio em cima do texto. Eu poderei receber textos nestes três formatos, sendo que o único que deverá receber um parágrafo a mais é o **texto 3**, pois ele não possui um parágrafo vazio em cima.

**Obs:** (com ou sem style e classe), o problema acontece por causa disso.

**texto 1:**

```
<p  class="blablabla" style="" ></p>
<p>Nono nonono nonononono </p>
```

**texto 2:**

```
<p  class="blobloblo">&nbsp;</p>
<p>Nono nonono nonononono </p>
```

**texto 3:**

```
<p  class="blublublu" style="" ><span>nono nonono no</span></p>
<p>Nono nonono nonononono </p>
```

Aqui está o método que eu tenho, só que tem um problema, ele não está pegando somente o primeiro parágrafo, daí eu não sei o que fazer para ele fazer o **match** só do primeiro parágrafo:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {    
    var result = $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
    if (angular.isDefined(result)) {   
        result = result.replace(/\n/gim, '');
        if (!result.match(/^<p(.*)?>(\s|&nbsp;)<\/p>/gim)) {
            result = '<p class="paragraph-added"></p>' + result;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Eu não entendi o motivo da negativa... está bem claro o que preciso. Para qualquer um entender.

Comment: Essa pergunta eu também não entendi o negativo, mas na outra talvez negativaram porque é de infra do google. E o pior que vou passar pela mesma situação sua, na outra pergunta, porque pretendo usar o webview para exibir conteúdo meu hospedado e agora fiquei sabendo que google vai me bloquear por conta da nova politica deles.

Comment: O meu caso é que tem duas empresas que se uniram virando uma só, daí temos que juntar duas arquiteturas diferentes no mesmo app, na outra pergunta que fui negativado.

Comment: "Juntar duas arquiteturas no mesmo app": ok, isso realmente torra bastante a paciência, mas normalmente se faz isso criando uma camada de abstração de resgate de dados, então ele mastiga os dados para um modelo de dados padronizado útil para o app

Comment: Ao invés de regex se usasse [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) com `var el = domparsed.getElementsByTag('p');` e checar se existe o primeiro paragrafo `el[0]` é vazio com `el[0].textContent.trim() == ''`, já seria bem mais simples, então se não existir bastaria um `var novo = document.createElement('p'); p.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'; domparsed.insertBefore(novo, domparsed.firstChild);`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, vou tentar usar isso... e te respondo se funcionar. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: @IvanFerrer editei o comentário com algum código mais relevante

Comment: Hoje eu recebo um `json` com o HTML... em formato string, então eu preciso, fazer isso antes dele sair para o `ng-bind-html="saida"`, como eu poderia fazer ele ser um objeto DOM, antes de sair e ser renderizado na view? Teria que criar um elemento?

Comment: tipo isso?`var el = document.createElement('div');
                    el.setAttribute('id', 'content_text_materia');
                    el.innerHTML = result;`

Comment: Mas não era só add o paragrafo quando ele não existisse? Vou tentar reler a pergunta para ver se entendo melhor a sua necessidade.

Comment: Acho que funcionou cara, valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme sugestão do @GuilhermeNascimento, eu cheguei em uma solução:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = result;

   var paragraphs = el.getElementsByTagName('p');
   if (paragraphs.length && paragraphs[0].innerHTML != '' && paragraphs[0].innerHTML != '&nbsp;') {
      var novo = document.createElement('p'); 
          novo.setAttribute('class', 'paragraph-added')
          novo.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'; 
          el.insertBefore(novo, el.firstChild);
    }
    result = el.innerHTML;
    return result;
```

Comment: Sugestão no if: `if (paragraphs.length && !paragraphs[0].textContent.trim()) {`, se não necessitar de retrocompatibilidade (navegadores antigos como IE) `String.prototype.trim`

Comment: Não posso usar textContent porque ali vai ter conteúdo com `<span>`..., mas obrigado pelas dicas, vc ajudou muito. Eu sempre esqueço de pensar que trabalhar com DOM é muito mais prático e adequado.